# Differential equation $(\cos x - \sin x) \dfrac{dy}{dx}+(\cos x + \sin x)y=(\cos x + \sin x)$ given that $y=-1$ when $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation $(\cos x - \sin x) \dfrac{dy}{dx}+(\cos x + \sin x)y=(\cos x + \sin x)$ given that $y=-1$ when $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

I have done some rearranging and worked out the integrating factor:

$\dfrac{1}{\cos x -\sin x}$

I now have:

$\dfrac{y}{\cos x - \sin x}=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\cos x+ \sin x }{(\cos x- \sin x)^2} dx $

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, and I'm stuck at the moment. I tried expanding the denominator to get $1- \sin 2x$ but that doesn't feel helpful either.

How do I do the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\cos x - \sin x) \frac{dy}{dx}+(\cos x + \sin x)y=(\cos x + \sin x)\\
\frac{(\cos x - \sin x)}{(\cos x + \sin x)}\frac{dy}{dx}+y=1\\
\int\frac{dy}{1-y}=\int\frac{(\cos x + \sin x)}{(\cos x - \sin x)}dx=\int\frac{-d(\cos x - \sin x)}{(\cos x - \sin x)}\\
-\ln|1-y|=-\ln|\cos x-\sin x|+c\\
1-y=k(\cos x-\sin x)\\1-(-1)=k(0-1)\\k=-2\\
y=1+2(\cos x-\sin x)$$